# c# saving tabs using system.io;

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the below code.  I think I have pretty close to what I need.  There is a main tab at startout (which does not contain tb, tb1, tb2, and tb3.  Once I click the button, a tab is generated containing tb, tb1, tb2, tb3.

tb, tb1,tb2, and tb3 show errors of not existing.  I simply cannot figure out how to get these saved.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public string status = "no";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string name = txtName.Text;


            //validate information
            try { }
            catch { }

            //create new tab
            string title = name;
            TabPage myTabPage = new TabPage(title);
            tabControl1.TabPages.Add(myTabPage);


            //Add Labels

            Label lb = new Label();
            lb.Text = "Denomination:";
            lb.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(150, 75);
            lb.Name = "lbl";
            lb.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
            myTabPage.Controls.Add(lb);

            Label lb2 = new Label();
            lb2.Text = "Year:";
            lb2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(150, 120);
            lb2.Name = "lbl2";
            lb2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
            myTabPage.Controls.Add(lb2);

            Label lb3 = new Label();
            lb3.Text = "Grade:";
            lb3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(150, 165);
            lb3.Name = "lbl3";
            lb3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
            myTabPage.Controls.Add(lb3);

            Label lb4 = new Label();
            lb4.Text = "Mint Mark:";
            lb4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(150, 210);
            lb4.Name = "lbl4";
            lb4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
            myTabPage.Controls.Add(lb4);

            //Add text boxes

            TextBox tb = new TextBox();
            tb.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(250, 75);
            tb.Name = "txt";
            tb.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(184, 20);
            myTabPage.Controls.Add(tb);

            TextBox tb1 = new TextBox();
            tb1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(250, 120);
            tb1.Name = "txt1";
            tb1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(184, 20);
            myTabPage.Controls.Add(tb1);

            TextBox tb2 = new TextBox();
            tb2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(250, 165);
            tb2.Name = "txt2";
            tb2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(184, 20);
            myTabPage.Controls.Add(tb2);

            TextBox tb3 = new TextBox();
            tb3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(250, 210);
            tb3.Name = "txt3";
            tb3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(184, 20);
            myTabPage.Controls.Add(tb3);

            //put data inside of textboxes

            tb.Text = txtCoin.Text;
            tb1.Text = txtYear.Text;
            tb2.Text = txtGrade.Text;
            tb3.Text = txtMint.Text;

            // Add delete button

            Button bn = new Button();
            bn.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(560, 350);
            bn.Name = "btnDelete";
            bn.Text = "Delete";
            bn.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 50);
            bn.Click += MyClick;
            myTabPage.Controls.Add(bn);
        }

        private void MyClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 myform = new Form2();
            myform.ShowDialog();




            if (status == "yes")
            { tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tabControl1.SelectedTab); }

            status = "no";

        }

        private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {

            int counter;
            int ccounter;
            string outLine ;

            string pathFileName = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "coins.dat");

            StreamWriter writeIt = new StreamWriter(pathFileName);


            foreach (TabPage tabPage in tabControl1.TabPages)
            {


                if (tabControl1.TabCount > 1)
                {
                    outLine = tabPage + tb.Text + tb1.Text + tb2.Text + tb3.Text + "\t";
                    writeIt.WriteLine(outLine);
                }

                if (tabControl1.TabCount == 1)
                {
                    outLine = tabPage + "\t";
                    writeIt.WriteLine(outLine);
                }
            }


            writeIt.Close();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: **What error do you get** and where?

Comment: I get the error of tb,tb1,tb2, and tb3 not existing, therefor it won't compile its not able to save anything.  On my first If statement in the form_closing, technically that needs to be changed because the first form does not contain tb, tb1, tb2,tb3.  Only dynaically generated tabs get those variables.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store `tb1`, etc in fields in your form so they can be accessed by other methods.

Comment: tb1 is actually a textbox, why cant I pull from this?

Comment: @user1057227: Because it's a **local** variable. You need to learn about fields and variables.

Answer (score 1):

> tb, tb1,tb2, and tb3 show errors of not existing.

Yes, they would - you're declaring them as *local variables* within `button1_Click`. To access them from other methods, you'll either need to just examine the controls within the tab page, or declare them as *instance* variables instead. However, in that case you'd need to consider the fact that there may be multiple tab pages.

It sounds like you really just need to iterate over the controls within each tab page, and pick out the textboxes. Either that, or perhaps create your own subclass of `TabPage` which knows about the textboxes. Then you could find each instance of your custom TabPage and ask it to save itself.

Comment: Well, they are actually just text boxes, I cant understand why I can't just pull the data from them.

Comment: @user1057227: You can - but you can't refer to local variables you've declared in one method from a different method. It's *very* important that you understand how the language works around this - don't just find a solution to your current problem; try to understand where the error is coming from in the first place.

Comment: I think I somewhat see what your saying, so it needs to be declared as an instance varriable.  for tb.Text = txtCoin.Text how would you do this?

Comment: @user1057227: Given that you can have multiple tabs, I suspect you'll end up with problems if you try that. Using a subclass of `TabPage` which "knows" about the textboxes would probably be simpler.